# How to get Device log in Swift with print()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, logging, hook

As you know, In Objective-C, we can use `NSlog()` api to print some logs. `NSlog()` will insert log to the `ASL`(Apple System Log),so we can get some log from `asl` api with out custom log api. 
In Swift We can use `print()` to print some logs,but it will not insert the log to the ASL. so we cant get the logs from `ASL`.

So,the first question is what did `print()` does while we call it?

the second question is how can we get the logs in Swift **with out using `NSLog()` api** and **without using custom log api**?

the third question is can I hook the print() api?

Comment: If you want logs to go into the ASL, you need to use an API that logs there.  There's no way around it.  Use `NSLog`, `CocoaLumberjack` or roll your own.  You don't have a choice.  `print()` is a Swift runtime function.  You can't replace it unless you modify the runtime.

Comment: @Avi oh,what a sad message. I dont want to use custom log api to get the logs

Comment: `print` is just like `printf` in `C` that prints the string to `stdout`. you shouldn't expect it is a logger. that's what `NSLog` for.

Comment: So don't.  Use `NSLog()`.  It works the same way in Swift as it does in Objective-C.  You don't want to use the right tool for the job?  Too bad.

Comment: @Avi well, I'm working on a tool to get the device log, so the tool cant ensure the user of tool only use `NSLog`

Comment: why not give it a try? https://github.com/zhihuitang/SwiftMagic